# Specify Implemented Interface as an Attribute in C#

Tags: c#, plugins, reflection, interface, attributes

I'm looking for anyone that can identify if this is possible or not, I am currently writing a small but extensible application that will have a plugin architecture.

To ensure the application is applicably to the current application, I'm using a custom Attribute to attach to the assembly

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly)]
    class PluginAttributes: Attribute
    {
        public PluginAttributes(string name, string description, string version, string author)
        {
            Name = name;
            Description = description;
            Version = version;
            Author = author;
        }

        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string Description { get; private set; }
        public string Version { get; private set; }
        public string Author { get; private set; }
        public XXXXXX Implements { get; private set; }
    }
```

What I aiming for, is that the 'Implements' property will identify the appropriate plugin's Interface type. I have numerous interfaces defined in the library, such as ICompress, IEncrypt, ILogging, etc.

The attribute will be used to classify which type of plugin it is, without having to create a separate attribute for each.

I know I could have it passed as a string and use reflection, or use an enum, but I want the code to be as low-maintenance as possible, so that plugins can be developed without touching the core of the application.

Comment: So a single plugin cannot implement more than 1 interface? Doesn't seem very flexible to me.

Comment: XXXXXX can be of type 'Type'. I share the oppinion of @xxbbcc that to apply this attribute to an entire Assembly is not very flexible. Why don't you create an attribute that can be applied to a class? You then can request all classes that implement your attribute to get all plugins from the assembly.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much by design, as the intention is that you can mix and match the workflow with different plugins, and each interface is specific to a type of plugin, so each module should only be interested in implementing one process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made various of this type of plugin mechanism, and often it is easier to create an instance of the plugin class and check against various interfaces than to define it on a attribute or so. This will leave the door open for a plugin to implement more than one interface, which is nice.

You can do that like this using reflection (assuming you know the type name):

```
object plugin = Activator.CreateInstance("Assembly.Name", "Type.Class.Name");

if (plugin is ILogging)
{ ... }

if (plugin is IEncrypt)
{ ... }
```

For your current code, I suggest you to make the type of your `Implements` property `Type` and fill it using `typeof(ILogging)`, `typeof(IEncrypt)`, etc.

Comment: I thought about using `Type` but couldn't find any way of specifically limiting it to an Interface type, rather than any old Type, ideally something similar to generics `where T: interface` would have been great :)

Comment: Yeah, that isn't possible with your current design. That is why I suggest to drop that. :)